# .htaccess rule for directory

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, vbulletin

I've vBulletin forum installed in /forum directory on a website.

I'm trying to redirect /forum/xyz/ to /forum/abc-xyz-def/

I tried this rule in the .htaccess file of root:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/xyz/ /forum/abc-xyz-def/ [L,R=301]
```

I also tried above in the /forum/.htaccess but none worked.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/forum/xyz/ /forum/abc-xyz-def/
```

Comment: Could you please also try this one, redirect /forum/subforum/old_url.html to /forum/subforum/new_url.html

Answer (score 0):

In your `forum/.htaccess` put this code **before any other rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forum/

RewriteRule ^xyz/?$ abc-xyz-def/ [L,R=301,NC]

# your rest of rules
```

Comment: Tx for reply Anubhava, I didn't try this solution but good to know. I didn't try it because I don't have any rewrite rules in /forum/.htaccess file so I didn't want to touch it.